# Why does Oracle update its Java platform so much?

Tags: java

It seems every other week Oracle releases an update for Java and I get this wonderful pop up:

[image]

Comparing the amount of updates Java releases to every other software installed on my computer, Java puts out more updates than the rest combined.

Is there a reason for this ? Or are they just trying to be the most updated platform ?

Comment: I'm guessing they are fixing stuff. Unlike ADOBE and MICROSOFT (Skype) who're just breaking things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see all updates in the change log, for example for the Java 8 Runtime it's available here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8all-relnotes-2226344.html

Obviously they aren't fixing bugs for kicks. It's so that there are less errors in the software.